# How to use DataAnnotations attributes in mvc4 to check for a valid input

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I have a field that needs to be only numeric.

I'm looking for the way to validate this field to accept values more than 0 and do not accept character input

I have the following field definition in model:

```
[Range(1,int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage="Value must be at least 1")]
[RegularExpression("([1-9][0-9]*)", ErrorMessage="Must be numeric")]
public int SortOrder { get; set; }
```

and the following in cshtml file:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.SortOrder)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SortOrder)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SortOrder,"*")
```

Everything seems to be right, however, when I try to have character input, I have a validation error saying that "The SortOrder field is required"

I need this message to say "Must be numeric"

What am I missing here?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can associated a specific error message with a `[Required]` attribute. Note the `[RegularExpression]` attribute is not required (its effectively just repeating the `[Range]` attribute)

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Must be numeric")]
[Range(1,int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage="Value must be at least 1")]
public int SortOrder { get; set; }
```

The reason you were getting *"The SortOrder field is required"* when entering a non-numeric value is that it fails the 'required' validation (its required to be a number (`int`) but its not a number) and the default 'required' error message is displayed.